# What is the incentive to run a Stellar node?

Tags: stellar-core, nodes, validators

In bitcoin, miners are rewarded by minting new coins. What's the incentive to do so in Stellar?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think there is a classic money reward, but you will have other kind of reward/benefit.

I think you should run your own node if you created some service relying over stellar network.

This way you will connect to your horizon instead of using other service.
Furthermore you can configure your server to accept query only from your services.
Benefits:

- You have a fully-synced node, with a low server load
- Your service will continue to work with network related problems
- lot more...

Keep in mind:
according to [official documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html#level-of-participation-to-the-network), you can run your node in different ways accordingly to your necessities

Answer (score 10):

If you look at [the stellar dashboard](https://dashboard.stellar.org/) there's a list of validators. You will see names like FairX, IBM, Tempo, SatoshiPay, StellarPort etc. These are all businesses that are invested in the success of Stellar. Since it's very cheap to run a validator (it's comparable to running an email server) you don't need big incentives to become one. Just an interest in securing the network and making sure it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 9):

As some have noted in other answers, there is no direct monetary incentive in maintaining a node. This isn't *necessarily* bad news: if you look at Bitcoin's proof-of-work - and especially at how it became centralised over time  - then it makes some sense NOT to have a monetary incentive, and thus avoid the problems it can cause.